# empty include paths in cosmos db index policy

Tags: database, azure, nosql, cloud, azure-cosmosdb

I have a cosmos DB with the following index policy

```
{
    "indexingMode": "consistent",
    "automatic": true,
    "includedPaths": [],
    "excludedPaths": [
        {
            "path": "/*"
        },
        {
            "path": "/\"_etag\"/?"
        }
    ]
}
```

As you can see, `includedPaths` is empty but I am surprised to see that the index size is **62.6GB**. I am wondering what all data is there in the index when there is nothing to index (as per index policy).

Here is the other DB metrics
Data size -> 1.5TB

Index size -> 62.6GB

Document count -> 746M

Comment: I am not 100% sure but if I am not mistaken, it could be because of `_ts` property which I am told is automatically indexed. Can you please check that?

Comment: @GauravMantri _ts is a timestamp and would take 4 or 8 bytes max. So If I consider this to be index then it would be 746*8=5968MB=~6GB. So It should be max 6GB not 62GB

Comment: From this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/index-policy#includeexclude-strategy) - `If the indexing mode is set to consistent, the system properties id and _ts are automatically indexed.`. Could that be the reason?

Comment: then it would be 53GB around. I got your idea, I am further looking into it

Comment: Great! When you find it, please post your findings as answer. I would be really curious to know.

Comment: @GauravMantri Please look into this as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69873820/extra-size-required-to-index-a-new-field-in-cosmos-db

Comment: Remember that the index doesn't just include the key values but each value in the tree also needs a list of documents that match that path

Comment: what is meant by each value in the tree? can you please guide me with some example

Comment: http://muratbuffalo.blogspot.com/2018/08/schema-agnostic-indexing-with-azure.html