# Extra size required to index a new field in cosmos DB

Tags: database, azure, indexing, nosql, azure-cosmosdb

I have a cosmos DB with `~750M` documents whose total size is `~1.5TB`. Currently, `includedPaths` is empty, so I am assuming only the `id` field is indexed and this is also the partition key.

Now I want to `index` one more field which is 32 length string. So I want to understand how much extra storage it would require to store the same.

In more detail, I want to understand that whenever a field is indexed, what all data It stores further.

As per my understanding, It will store new field data and partition key data. So if the partition key is 50 length string then for each document it would require `32bytes + 50 bytes = 82 bytes`. As there are `~750M` documents, it will be `750M*82=~61GB` extra storage.

Comment: I'm not sure how this question is different from your [first question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69864282/empty-include-paths-in-cosmos-db-index-policy) about indexing and space.

Comment: That said: your calculations are not accurate, as there is additional storage for encoding, along with any other properties indexed (it's not just `id` - there are other internal properties). It's just not as simple as you're assuming it might be.